# Issues with redirect rules to redirect all URLs except one page

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I need to add following Apache redirect rules to `.htaccess`:

`http://www.example.com` to be redirected to `http://www.onemoreexample.com`

but `http://www.example.com/support` should not be redirected.

To achieve this, I added the redirect rules below:

```
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onemoreexample.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

But `http://www.example.com/support/` is taking me to `http://www.onemoreexample.com/support/` after adding the above rule

Following rules also exist before the above rules to redirect to www.

```
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

My .htaccess file looks like this

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

   # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
   RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
   RewriteRule . index.php [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support/
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onemoreexample.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? Is `/support` a physical directory? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: On the face of it there is nothing _wrong_ with the directive you posted, so there must be something else affecting this. We need more information about your config... other Apache / `.htaccess` directives and filesystem structure.

Comment: There is a  rule to redirect to www above this rule . I have added this info in original description

Comment: And what is `/support`? How is this routed to return a response? To confirm... `/support` is not being redirect, but `/support/` is?

Comment: Yeah...It is /support/  .. I later realized there is a trailing / which I added later but still no luck

Comment: no physical directory exist for /support/ . It is an extension of wordpress multisite feature

Comment: "Yeah...It is /support/" - what do you mean by this? So, is the request for `/support` or `/support/` or both and neither, both or one or the other is redirected? "It is an extension of wordpress multisite feature" - Ah, so you must have other WordPress related directives that route the request. Please include your entire `.htaccess` file.

Comment: The request is for /support/ .  Also shared .htaccess file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In isolation, the redirect directives themselves are OK, so there must be something else going on...

Having looked at your `.htaccess` file as a whole, with the redirect directives in-place, I'm surprised your redirect directives are actually doing anything(?!), since you've put them in the wrong place at the end of the `.htaccess` file, after the WordPress multisite directives.

Since there is no physical directory (or file) called `/support` then WordPress rewrites this request to `/index.php` *before* your redirect occurs and processing stops before your redirect is even processed. (So, how this is seemingly redirecting the request is not clear - the obvious guess would be that you are seeing a cached redirect (after some earlier testing perhaps) - or there is *something else* entirely that is triggering the redirect?)

Generally, *external redirects* should always go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* any rewrites. So your `.htaccess` file should look something like the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# External redirects...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onemoreexample.com/$1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]


# WordPress multisite rewrites...
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

You will need to ensure the browser cache is clear before testing.

> **UPDATE#1:** It resolves but the CSS breaks

The above will also redirect any static resources (CSS, JS, images) that are not also referenced with the `/support/...` URL-path prefix. If the corresponding CSS files are not also located at the redirected domain then your CSS will break. This maybe what's happening here... (but, assuming these are shared/common CSS resources I would have expected this to break for all the redirected pages as well? Unless perhaps the CSS used by the `/support/` page is unique?).

To exclude CSS and other static resources you would need to add another exception. For example:

```
# Redirect everything except "/support/..." and other static resources
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|jpg|gif|png)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onemoreexample.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

> **UPDATE#2** one more issue... `http://www.example.com/support/wp-admin` should not be redirected too but it is getting redirected to `http://www.onemoreexample.com/wp-login.php`.

The issue here is that `/support/wp-admin` is first being redirected to `/wp-login.php` (no `/support/` prefix) by WordPress on the same domain which will then get redirected to your other domain with the directive above. So, you will need to make an exception for `/wp-login.php` as well, if you don't want unauthenticated users that visit `/support/wp-admin` being redirected.

For example, change the first condition to read something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(support/|wp-login\.php$)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will test it after sometime

Comment: Just an observation...  It actually works If I put the redirect rules after `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` in .htaccess but it breaks the CSS formatting of /support. If I keep the rules as in answer section , /support continues to redirect to http://www.onemoreexample.com

Comment: It shouldn't matter whether you put these directives before or after `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` (not sure why it would break the CSS formatting when placed _after_?) - although it is more _logical_ to place them at the top of the file. The important thing is that they are placed _before_ the `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` (and corresponding _conditions_) rule. "If I keep the rules as in answer section" - do you mean "in your question"? My _answer_ is in the "answer section".

Comment: Yeah... I was referring to your answer section

Comment: So, your problem is _not_ resolved??

Comment: It resolves but the CSS breaks

Comment: What URL are you using to reference your CSS? Do `example.com` and `onemoreexample.com` point to the same place?

Comment: Both are different.. we are decommissioning example.com and so we are rewriting to onemoreexample.com except example.com/support.. CSS is breaking for /support when the rewrite rules are working as expected

Comment: The CSS URLs are probably being redirected and if these files don't exist at `onemoreexample.com` then the CSS will naturally break. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It seems CSS are loading fine now . We are testing further . Thanks so much. You are Awesome!

Comment: I am back with one more issue...  `http://www.example.com/support/wp-admin` should not be redirected too but it is getting redirected to `http://www.onemoreexample.com/wp-login.php` . I tried with this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/support/|/support/wp\-admin/wp\-login\.php/)` but no luck...Any suggestions please ?

Comment: It would seem to be the `/wp-login.php` URL that is being redirected (because WP itself first redirects unauthenticated users to login), but you've included an exception for `/support/wp-admin/wp-login.php/` in the condition - so I can't see that this would ever match? I would assume you need to exclude `/wp-login.php`? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks again . It is working now . One query ..since there is no $ sign after `!^/support` in the first rule , is it by default not suppose to have redirected to `wp-login.php` page

Comment: It didn't redirect `/support/wp-admin`, because (as you rightly say) there is no `$` sign (end-of-string anchor). However, WordPress (PHP code) did. WordPress itself redirected to `/wp-login.php`, not your directive. The directive in `.htaccess` would then have redirected (a second redirect) to the other domain, since we did not have an exception for `/wp-login.php`. If you looked at the network traffic, you should have seen two separate redirects. This obviously means that any direct request for `/wp-login.php` will now not be redirected.

Comment: Something weird happening...  After I entered the correct credentials in wp-login.php , it is redirecting me to `http://www.onemoreexample.com/wp-login.php` instead of showing admin dashboard

Comment: Following are seeing in log after I enter the admin credentials  `POST /support/wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 302`  `GET /support/wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302`

Comment: It works after adding below rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(support/|wp-admin/)`

Comment: I can imagine you could still run into difficulties like that. You'll need to monitor what requests are made for the functions you need to perform and make the necessary exceptions. The condition you've added implies there is a request for `/wp-admin/...` (no `/support` prefix), which appears to contradict the log entry you've posted? Incidentally, you don't need to repeat the `support/` exception in that second rule if it's still present in the first.

Comment: Actually I replaced the first rule `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(support/|wp-login\.php$)` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(support/|wp-admin/) ` to make it work . Let's see if we encounter further issues .

Comment: BTW , Can you please the explain the `Pipe (|)` symbol in your rule before `wp-login\.php` from `!^/(support/|wp-login\.php$)`

Comment: The pipe symbol is used to express [_alternation_](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) (ie. logical OR) in a regular expression (regex). For example, the regex `(support/|wp-login\.php$)` matches either `support/` OR `wp-login.php`. (The `$` in the second part indicates that nothing can come after `wp-login.php`.) It's the same regex syntax that PHP, JavaScript and other languages use.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `/?` to consider optional trailing slash as well in rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/support/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.onemoreexample.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Tried but no luck

Comment: With the regex `^/support` (with no trailing end-of-string anchor) everything after the pattern is already optional.